# pyocrがimportできない

Tags: python, python3

PythonでpdfからOCRをしたくて、
https://imagisi.com/ocr-python/
上記のページを参考にしていたのですが、
Windows 10のAnacondaで作成したPython3.6の仮想環境のJupterlab上で

```
import pyocr
```

を実行したところ、下記のエラーが出ます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ilab2\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-10-8d1d5df63604>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyocr

  File "C:\Users\ilab2\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pyocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyocr import *

  File "C:\Users\ilab2\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pyocr\pyocr.py", line 50, in <module>
    from . import tesseract

  File "C:\Users\ilab2\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pyocr\tesseract.py", line 168
    def detect_orientation(image,lang=None):
                                            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

errorを参考に該当のファイル（pyocr\tesseract.py）の168行目を確認したのですが、原因がわかりません。
原因と解決方法をご教授いただければ幸いです。
（def detect_orientation(image,lang=None):の行頭のインデントはこうなっていました）。

```
def detect_orientation(image,lang=None):
"""
Arguments:
    image --- Pillow image to analyze
    lang --- lang to specify to tesseract

Returns:
    {
        'angle': 90,
        'confidence': 23.73,8
    }

Raises:
    TesseractError --- if no script detected on the image
"""
_set_environment()
    with temp_dir() as tmpdir:
        command = [TESSERACT_CMD, "input.bmp", 'stdout', "--psm", "0"]
        version = get_version()
    if version[0] >= 4:
        # XXX: temporary fix to remove once Tesseract 4 is stable
        command += ["--oem", "0"]
    if lang is not None:
        command += ['-l', lang]

    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image.save(os.path.join(tmpdir, "input.bmp"))

    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False,
                            startupinfo=g_subprocess_startup_info,
                            creationflags=g_creation_flags,
                            cwd=tmpdir,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    proc.stdin.close()
    original_output = proc.stdout.read()
    proc.wait()

    original_output = original_output.decode("utf-8")
    original_output = original_output.strip()
    try:
        output = original_output.split("\n")
        output = [line.split(": ", 1) for line in output if (": " in line)]
        output = {x: y for (x, y) in output}
        angle = int(output.get('Rotate', output['Orientation in degrees']))
        # Tesseract reports the angle in the opposite direction the one we
        # want
        angle = (360 - angle) % 360
        return {
            'angle': angle,
            'confidence': float(output['Orientation confidence']),
        }
    except:
        raise TesseractError(-1, "No script found in image (%s)"
                             % original_output)
```

### 追記

コメントで勧められたとおり、一度pyocrを削除（Anaconda prompt上で conda uninstall pyocr)し、再度インストール（[https://anaconda.org/brianjmcguirk/pyocrを参考にconda](https://anaconda.org/brianjmcguirk/pyocr%E3%82%92%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E3%81%ABconda) install -c brianjmcguirk pyocr）したところ、無事importできました。
今まではJupyter lab上で

```
!conda install -c brianjmcguirk pyocr
```

としていたのですが、Safty error?が出ていたようです（再現できないのですが、File sizeが異なるというような内容のエラーだったかと思います）。
Jupyter lab上で行う!マークを付けたconda installは、Anaconda prompt上でconda installを行うのと同じという認識でしたがよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: オリジナルのソースコードを見る限り数年前から `detect_orientation` 関数のインデントはこうなっていそうだったので修正しましたが、もしお手元のソースコードと異なっていれば再修正をお願いします。（Markdown のコード記法が行頭にスペース4つ入れるという文法な影響で、最初の行だけスペースが入っていて後の行に入れ忘れているよくあるミスだと判断しました）

Comment: ありがとうございます！
頂いたコメント・インデント部分を修正したのですが同様のエラーが出ます。

Comment: む、これはお手元の `detect_orientation` のソースコードがこうなっているので間違いないですか？　であればこのインデントがエラーの原因なのですが、オリジナルのリポジトリではこのようなコードにはなっていないので謎です。一度 pyocr をアンインストールして再度インストールしても同じソースコードになりますか？

Comment: エラーメッセージに示されている問題発生行は、pyocrの最新版(0.7.2)では168行目ではなく176行目です。何か古い(or別の)版がインストールされているか、何らかの理由で書き換えられている可能性が考えられます。アンインストール/再インストールで直るかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 手元の pyocr のソースコードではインデントが壊れていた。
- `!conda install pyocr` をした際に Safety error が出ていた。

ということから判断すると、インストール時にネットワーク不調かなにかでバイト欠損が生じたのかもしれません。エラーに再現性が無いことからも、低確率で起こるエラーだったのではないかと推測します。あるいは他に考えられる理由としては一時的にライブラリ配布元のデータが壊れていた可能性があります。

理由はともあれ IndentationError は手元のライブラリのソースコードでインデントがずれていたからで、ライブラリを一度アンインストールして再度インストールすると直ったのであれば以降は問題ないでしょう。

> Jupyter lab上で行う!マークを付けたconda installは、Anaconda prompt上でconda installを行うのと同じという認識でしたがよろしいでしょうか。

こちらに関して、はい、その通りです。今回の問題はインストール方法に起因するものではなく、何かしらインストール途中のどこかの手順が失敗したのではないかと私は推測しています。

Comment: nekketsuuu♦さん
ご回答、わかりやすく丁寧にありがとうございます。
バイト欠損という現象があるのですね。
勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

最初に提示された [【文字起こし】pythonでOCRを使ってみた](https://imagisi.com/ocr-python/) に記述された通りの手順で pyocr をインストールしていなかったのが原因でしょう。
追記されたアンインストール/再インストールの手順も、記事に書かれた以下とは違うので微妙ですが、それで動作したなら一応結果オーライでしょうね。

> **pyocrのインストール**
>
> では最後にpyocrをインストールします。これはpythonでOCRを使うことができるようにするためのモジュールです。
> これは簡単で **AnacondaPromptで**
>
> 1| pip install pyocr
>
> とすればインストールできます。

---

上記記事に書かれている、condaによるtesseractのインストールと、pipによるpyocrのインストールを混ぜているのは、危ない可能性があるのでどうかと思いますが、そのとおりに作業すれば記事の通りに動作は正常に出来ました。

参照した記事があるなら、先ずはその記述のとおりに作業してみてください。

違う手順を混ぜたり、そこでエラーが発生したりしていたなら、質問記事にはその詳細を記述しておいてください。

---

「Jupyter lab上で行う!マークを付けた...」に関連して見つかる記述は以下くらいでしょうか。

[Jupyter 知っておくと少し便利なTIPS集](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/d7dccb798f0b9c8b1ec5)
[!マークを付けると、コマンドが使える](https://qiita.com/simonritchie/items/d7dccb798f0b9c8b1ec5#%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

> pipコマンドなどは、結構ノート上で使うこともあります。ただし、pipでライブラリ設定などを変えた際には、ノートのカーネルを一度再起動しないと反映されません。（ノートブックサーバーなどは起動したまま行えます）
> 引数に、ノート上の変数を指定したい場合なとには$の記号を変数の前に置くと使えます。
>
> **実は一部コマンドはそのまま実行できる**
>
> マジックコマンドや、!の記号をつけなくても、一部コマンドはそのままノート上で実行できます。
> lsコマンドなど。引数も認識してくれます。

Comment: conda と pip は異なるパッケージマネージャです。二者を同時に使うと後々依存性解析に失敗する可能性があります。pip を使うにしても conda environment で最終手段として使うなどに留めるべきです。

Comment: それは認識していて、回答にも少し言及していますよ。ただ参照記事では動作していますし、こちらでも動作しました。それが問題だと思って別の方法を取ったなら、それも質問に書いてあれば、それでも良かったのですがね。行ったことが正確では無いと状況判断や調査に無駄や狂いが出てきます。

Comment: はい、書いてあるのは分かっていましたが、だからといってブログ記事を鵜呑みにして実行することを勧めるのはいかがなものかと思いコメントしました。また、回答としてどういう手順を勧めるかと、質問の書き方をどうすべきかは分けて考えるべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: その辺は感じ方考え方の差ですかね。質問側の経験・知識の雰囲気と参照記事内容が最近のものという兼ね合いで、先ずは書いてある通りに作業するのが筋が通っていると考えたので。そこで何か問題が出たなら、それを基に質問してもらえば良い訳ですし。

Comment: kunifさん
＞参照した記事があるなら、先ずはその記述のとおりに作業してみてください。

＞違う手順を混ぜたり、そこでエラーが発生したりしていたなら、質問記事にはその詳細を記述しておいてください。
複数の知見を独自に解釈して、それを質問に書かなかったのは私の落ち度です。
混乱させてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。
また参考に挙げていただいた記事も勉強になりました。
今回初めてStack overflowに質問を投稿させていただきましたが、今後質問の仕方には気を付けます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: Anaconda環境でやっているとtesseractもpyocrも少し古い版数なので、実際に処理する場合はAnaconda/JupyterLabではない環境に移行した方が良さそうです。